# Allow Cloudflare API traffic

Tags: cloudflare

Is it possible to transfer API traffic through Cloudflare from a subdomain with a free plan?
Or is the only solution to send traffic directly to the server?

I know there is an API Shield, but it is only for the Enterprise plan.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the primary, root domain on Cloudflare already, then there is nothing stopping you from having Cloudflare proxy the API traffic on your subdomain as well. You would still get some benefit from the standard/free Cloudflare Web Application Firewall and DDOS protection. You just wouldn't have the specific API Shield features available to you.

Comment: The problem is that if I access the php file through the same postman, then I do not receive an API response, but a response from CF that wants to write a cookie. Without this cookie, CF does not allow you to receive a response

Comment: That sounds like Cloudflare bot protection or something. You will need to create a new page rule for your API subdomain, that has different security settings.

Comment: But I didn’t understand exactly how to set this up.
You cannot change the security level to off on the free plan.